# Is it possible to change the icon of a compiled iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I was wondering if it is possible to change the icon of an iOS app without recompiling it every single time. I would like to create a personal app where I can change the icon very easily.

Comment: So write a script to automatically recompile it.

Comment: Yeah, that ended up being the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new API that was announced with iOS 10.3 that can help you with this, otherwise, it is not possible. Here is some sample code on how to use it: https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/AlternateIconTest